# How to read and display records one at a time in the COBOL program below?

Tags: file-io, cobol

I am trying to write a ***COBOL*** program to read a file "INPUT.TXT" with 4 fields as given below and display the details of students. But the records are not read and displayed one by one.

I am using http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cobol_online.php for the program.
The records in "INPUT.TXT" (**please note that the input file is a simple text file)**  are:

```
EMPID  NAME     COMPANY          RATING

112211 UMESH    CAPGEMINI        A
221122 ISHAN    ZALONI           A
134231 AJMERA   GOOGLE           B
232144 NIYANTA  WIPRO            B
561144 KANKANA  ZETA             A
324556 CHRISTOPHER  TCS          C
123443 SIDDIKA       TCS         A
```

PROGRAM:

```
 IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
 PROGRAM-ID. SAMPLE1.                 

 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
 INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
 FILE-CONTROL.
 SELECT EMPFILE  ASSIGN TO 'input.txt'
 ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL       
 ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL
 FILE STATUS IS WS-FILE-STATUS. 
 DATA DIVISION.
 FILE SECTION.                        
 FD EMPFILE.                          
  01  NEWFILE.                         
      05  EMPID  PIC 9(7).          
      05  NAME   PIC A(22).                              
      05  COMPANY PIC X(10). 
      05  RATING  PIC X(1).
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.    
  01    WS-EOF         PIC A(1)  VALUE "N".                     
  01    WS-FILE-STATUS PIC X(2).  

 PROCEDURE DIVISION.

 MAIN-PARA.
   OPEN INPUT  EMPFILE
   PERFORM READ-PARA THRU READ-PARA-EXIT UNTIL WS-EOF="Y"
   STOP RUN.                                             
 MAIN-PARA-EXIT.
 EXIT.

 READ-PARA.
 READ EMPFILE                                         
 AT END                                               
   MOVE "Y" TO WS-EOF                                  
 NOT AT END                                           
   DISPLAY "*****"  NEWFILE
 END-READ.
 READ-PARA-EXIT.
 EXIT.
```

Comment: @lostsock YOUR EDIT RUINED IT (-:

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what goes wrong? It seems to at least *almost* work.

Comment: *****112211 UMESH    CAPGEMINI        A
2211
*****22 ISHAN    ZALONI      A
134231 AJMERA
*****   GOOGLE      B
232144 NIYANTA  WIPRO 
*****     B
561144 KANKANA  ZETA      A
324
*****556 CHRISTOPHER  TCS  C
ETA      A
324

Comment: I think the issue is that you missed reading the line break. See also my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit I've never seen COBOL before, so I hope this is no nonsense. :)

It seems you are opening the file as a sequential file with fixed length records that should match the total length of the EMPFILE type. It seems there are two issues.

**Mind the header:**
There is a problem with the offset, and that is due to the length of the header line and the white line after it. So you should either remove those from input.txt (if you can), or somehow skip these lines. Maybe you can do that by defining a different type that has the size of the header, and then read that once to skip those bytes.

For a first test, you can just remove the header line from input.txt, to make it easier to get the other part right.

**Mind the break:**
You specify the sizes of the individual fields, but they seem to be wrong, or `input.txt` didn't survive being posted on SO. :) I get better results with this.

```
 FD EMPFILE.                          
  01  NEWFILE.                         
      05  EMPID  PIC 9(7).          
      05  NAME   PIC A(9).                              
      05  COMPANY PIC X(17). 
      05  RATING  PIC X(1).
      05  BREAK   PIC X(2).
```

The most important change here is the BREAK to read the line break. This seems to be necessary, otherwise the line break (2 bytes in my case, although it might be 1 in yours) seems to be read as the first two chracters of the id of the next record.

I changed some of the other counts to match the input as I got it, although maybe some spaces have been lost in the copy-pasting around, you should check your input file again to check the field lengths.

Then you can also display the individual fields instead of the entire EMPFILE line, so you can easily check if you got all of the field sizes right:

So `DISPLAY EMPFILE` becomes:

```
DISPLAY EMPID
DISPLAY NAME
DISPLAY COMPANY
DISPLAY RATING
```

Which eventually gave me this output:

```
112211 
UMESH        
CAPGEMINI        
A
221122 
ISHAN        
ZALONI           
A
134231 
AJMERA       
GOOGLE           
B
232144 
NIYANTA      
WIPRO            
B
561144 
KANKANA      
ZETA             
A
324556 
CHRISTOPHER  
TCS              
C
123443 
SIDDIKA      
TCS              
A
WARNING - Implicit CLOSE of EMPFILE ("input.txt")
```

I did realign input.txt, because I felt it was messed up.

If that works alright, you can move on to the next problem, which is handling the header.

Comment: sorry for asking this...but I didn't get the 1st part...what's a header? what's a header line ? what's an offset?...please reply

Comment: I just meant the first line in `input.txt`, that contains the column names. That line has a different length than the other lines, mainly because of the column name 'RANKING', which is obviously longer than the single-character value on the following lines. So if you read that line as if it was a normal 'data' line, you would start at the wrong position (offset) when reading the second line.

Comment: k thanx...one more question....how do i store the input in the form of a table in the text file "input.txt" and what if i need to display all those employees who have got a rating B...For eg.                                                                                                                                                         134231 AJMERA   GOOGLE           B
                232144 NIYANTA  WIPRO            B

Comment: I think that question and its answer are too big to be handled in comments. If your current question is answered, you can mark an answer as 'accepted' if you like. For additional questions, just ask a new question, so there is room for new answers by other people as well.

Answer (score 3):

I used your code with some minimal changes, I get the below output:

```
*******112211 UMESH    CAPGEMINI        A

*******221122 ISHAN    ZALONI           A

*******134231 AJMERA   GOOGLE           B

*******232144 NIYANTA  WIPRO            B

*******561144 KANKANA  ZETA             A

*******324556 CHRISTOPHER  TCS          C

*******123443 SIDDIKA       TCS         A
```

The program that I used:

```
     IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
 PROGRAM-ID. SAMPLE1.                 

 ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
 INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
 FILE-CONTROL.
 SELECT EMPFILE  ASSIGN TO 'input.txt'
 ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL       
 ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL
 FILE STATUS IS WS-FILE-STATUS. 
 DATA DIVISION.
 FILE SECTION.                        
 FD EMPFILE.                          
  01  NEWFILE.                         
      05  EMPID  PIC 9(6).          
      05  NAME   PIC A(10).                              
      05  COMPANY PIC X(17). 
      05  RATING  PIC X(1).
      05  FILLER  PIC XX. 
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.    
  01    WS-EOF         PIC A(1)  VALUE "N".                     
  01    WS-FILE-STATUS PIC X(2).  

 PROCEDURE DIVISION.

 MAIN-PARA.
   OPEN INPUT  EMPFILE.
   PERFORM READ-PARA THRU READ-PARA-EXIT UNTIL WS-EOF="Y".
   CLOSE EMPFILE.
   STOP RUN.                                             
 MAIN-PARA-EXIT.
 EXIT.

 READ-PARA.
 MOVE ZERO TO EMPID. 
 READ EMPFILE                                         
 AT END                                               
   MOVE "Y" TO WS-EOF                                  
 NOT AT END                                           
   DISPLAY  '*******', NEWFILE
 END-READ.

 READ-PARA-EXIT.
 EXIT.
```

Also, please note that the input file had no header in my test. 
To solve that, you need to just read 2 lines and than do the rest.

The issue with the reading is not with the code, but the input - or how is the NEWFILE declared. You need to respect the length of the line to the last space in order to get a good result. In your case, the lines in the input need to have exacly 40 characters. Also, if you have a header, than make that also 40 chars and then read it.

112211 UMESH    CAPGEMINI        A

In this line, you need the following declaration:

```
01  NEWFILE.                         
      05  EMPID  PIC 9(6).          
      05  NAME   PIC A(10).                              
      05  COMPANY PIC X(17). 
      05  RATING  PIC X(1).
```

With no spaces at the end, and all lines the same length, this will work.

Also, the input file needed some edit (used spaces instead of tabs).

```
112211 UMESH    CAPGEMINI        A
221122 ISHAN    ZALONI           A
134231 AJMERA   GOOGLE           B
232144 NIYANTA  WIPRO            B
561144 KANKANA  ZETA             A
324556 CHRISTOPHER  TCS          C
123443 SIDDIKA       TCS         A
```

Let me know if you need more explanations.

Comment: i didn't get the header part... what's a header? and here, where is it ??

Comment: The header is this line of the input:EMPID  NAME     COMPANY          RATING